# Necessity of nonnegative terms in reversing order of summation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

In real analysis:

Let $\mu$ be a counting measure on $\mathbb N$ and $a_{ij} \ge 0$ for $i,j=1,2....$.

we know that

$\sum_{i} \sum_{j}a_{ij} = \sum_{j} \sum_{i}a_{ij} $.

But why the condition $a_{ij} \ge 0$ is essential?

Can you give an example to show that the condition is essential?

Answer (score 1):

Define $a_{ij}$ by $a_{ii} = + 1$, $a_{ij} = -1$ if $j = i - 1$, and $0$ in all other cases. Think of this as an infinite matrix with $+1$ on the main diagonal and $-1$ on the subdiagonal.

Then summing in $i$ first sums over rows then columns:

$$\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} a_{ij} = 1 + 0 + 0 + ... = 1$$

On the other hand, summing in $j$ first sums over columns then rows:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} a_{ij} = 0 + 0 + 0 + ...= 0$$

Comment: goooooooooooooooood.

Answer (score 0):

Take for example
$$
 a_{ij} =
 \begin{cases}
  -1 & \text{if $i \geq j$} \\
   1 & \text{if $i < j$}
 \end{cases}.
$$
Then $\sum_{i \geq 0} \sum_{j \geq 0} a_{ij} = \infty$ but $\sum_{j \geq 0} \sum_{i \geq 0} a_{ij} = -\infty$.

PS: It is worth noticing that by Fubini’s theorem the order of the sums can always be reversed if $\sum_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}} |a_{ij}| < \infty$. So strictly speaking the condition $a_{ij} \geq 0$ for all $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$ is not necessary, but sufficient.